# Define priority_queue with lambda in header file

Tags: c++

I have a question about defining a `priority_queue` pointer in header file and initializing it in source file.

**header file**

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Process>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>>, ?> *readyQueue;
```

**source file**

```
auto readyQueueComparator = [](const std::shared_ptr<Process> &first, const std::shared_ptr<Process> &second) {
        return true;
    };
readyQueue = new std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Process>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>>, decltype(readyQueueComparator)>;
```

Basically, I want to implement a structure like this but I couldn't figure out how should I define priority queue in header file in this format.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use a lambda here.  I'd just write a functor.  I'd also avoid having a global variable if it can be helped.

Comment: That won't be possible with lambda, since it's type is unknown. On a side note, I am not sure if there is really a reason to have a pointer to priority_queue in the program.

Comment: @SergeyA Let's say that I won't use a pointer to priority_queue, but I still want that as a member variable in a class. (I didn't put the whole code, but ready_queue is actually a member variable.) How should I define priority_queue in header file in this case?

Comment: @MertAkozcan pointer note was a side note. The actual answer is that you can't use lambda's type before you define the lambda. You can use a functor  like shown in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is don't use a lambda for this.  Define a custom callable type instead.  For example:

```
struct OrderByProcessPriority
{
  bool operator()(
    std::shared_ptr<Process> const& first,
    std::shared_ptr<Process> const& second) const;
}

using ProcessQueue = std::priority_queue<
  std::shared_ptr<Process>,
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>>,
  OrderByProcessPriority>;

ProcessQueue *readyQueue;
```

Then, in your cpp file, create the instance like this:

```
readyQueue = new ProcessQueue{};
```